# Question about the proof of Lemma 14.19 (Maximum Principle) in Jech's Set Theory

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

$B$: the complete Boolean algebra. $V^B$: the $B$-valued model.

> **Lemma 14.18.** If $W$ is a set of pairwise disjoint elements of $B$ and if $a_u$ (where $u\in W$) are elements of $V^B$, then there exists some $a\in V^B$ such that $u\leq||a=a_u||$ for all $u\in W$.
>
> **Lemma 14.19** $V^B$ is full. Given a formula $\varphi(x,\ldots)$, there exists some $a\in V^B$ such that $||\varphi(a,\ldots)||=||\exists x\varphi(x,\ldots)||$.
>
> *Proof.* We wish to find an $a\in V^B$ such that $\geq$ holds Let $u_0=||\exists x\varphi(x,\ldots)||$. Let
>   $$
> D=\{u\in B:\textrm{there is some }a_u\textrm{ such that }u\leq||\varphi(a_u,\ldots)||\}.
> $$
>   It is clear that $D$ is open and dense below $u_0$. Let $W$ be a maximal set of pairwise disjoint elements of $D$; clearly, $\sum\{u:u\in W\}\geq u_0$. By Lemma 14.18 thre exists some $a\in V^B$ such that $u\leq\||a=a_u||$ for some $u\in W$. Thus for each $u\in W$ we have $u\leq||\varphi(a,\ldots)||$, and hence $u_0\leq||\varphi(a,\ldots)||$.

I don't know why we need $D$ is open. More specifically, if $D$ is dense below $u_0$, I think we would have the followings:

(i) $\sum D=u_0$

(ii) $\sum W$= $\sum D$.

Then $\sum W=u_0$ and the left proceeding still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that $D$ is open and are correct about all three statements.

I can only guess why Jech mentions that $D$ is also open here but, in any case, you'll find this sort of unnecessary information in mathematical proofs all the time for a plethora of possible reasons.